# Istio authorization policy not applying on child gateway

Tags: kubernetes, istio

**What I am trying to achieve:** block all traffic to a service, containing the code to handle this within the same namespace as the service.

**Why:** this is the first step in "locking down" a specific service to specific IPs/CIDRs

I have a primary ingress GW called `istio-ingressgateway` which works for services.

```yaml
$ kubectl describe gw istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system
Name:         istio-ingressgateway
Namespace:    istio-system
Labels:       operator.istio.io/component=IngressGateways
              operator.istio.io/managed=Reconcile
              operator.istio.io/version=1.5.5
              release=istio
Annotations:  API Version:  networking.istio.io/v1beta1
Kind:         Gateway
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2020-08-28T15:45:10Z
  Generation:          1
  Resource Version:    95438963
  Self Link:           /apis/networking.istio.io/v1beta1/namespaces/istio-system/gateways/istio-ingressgateway
  UID:                 ae5dd2d0-44a3-4c2b-a7ba-4b29c26fa0b9
Spec:
  Selector:
    App:    istio-ingressgateway
    Istio:  ingressgateway
  Servers:
    Hosts:
      *
    Port:
      Name:      http
      Number:    80
      Protocol:  HTTP
Events:          <none>
```

I also have another "primary" GW, the K8s ingress GW to support TLS (thought I'd include this, to be as explicit as possible)

```yaml
k describe gw istio-autogenerated-k8s-ingress -n istio-system
Name:         istio-autogenerated-k8s-ingress
Namespace:    istio-system
Labels:       app=istio-ingressgateway
              istio=ingressgateway
              operator.istio.io/component=IngressGateways
              operator.istio.io/managed=Reconcile
              operator.istio.io/version=1.5.5
              release=istio
Annotations:  API Version:  networking.istio.io/v1beta1
Kind:         Gateway
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2020-08-28T15:45:56Z
  Generation:          2
  Resource Version:    95439499
  Self Link:           /apis/networking.istio.io/v1beta1/namespaces/istio-system/gateways/istio-autogenerated-k8s-ingress
  UID:                 edd46c17-9975-4089-95ff-a2414d40954a
Spec:
  Selector:
    Istio:  ingressgateway
  Servers:
    Hosts:
      *
    Port:
      Name:      http
      Number:    80
      Protocol:  HTTP
    Hosts:
      *
    Port:
      Name:      https-default
      Number:    443
      Protocol:  HTTPS
    Tls:
      Credential Name:     ingress-cert
      Mode:                SIMPLE
      Private Key:         sds
      Server Certificate:  sds
Events:                    <none>
```

I want to be able to create another GW, in the namespace `x` and have an authorization policy attached to that GW.
If I create the authorization policy in the `istio-system` namespace, then it comes back with `RBAC: access denied` which is great - but that is for all services using the primary GW.

```yaml
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: block-all
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: istio-ingressgateway
  action: DENY
  rules:
    - from:
        - source:
            ipBlocks: ["0.0.0.0/0"]
```

What I currently have does not work. Any pointers would be highly appreciated. The following are all created under the `x` namespace when applying the `kubectl apply -f files.yaml -n x`

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  annotations:
      app: x-ingress
  name: x-gw
  labels:
    app: x-ingress
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - hosts:
        - x.y.com
      port:
        name: http
        number: 80
        protocol: HTTP
      tls:
        httpsRedirect: true
    - hosts:
        - x.y.com
      port:
        name: https
        number: 443
        protocol: HTTPS
      tls:
        mode: SIMPLE
        privateKey: sds
        serverCertificate: sds
        credentialName: ingress-cert
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: x
  labels:
    app: x
spec:
  hosts:
    - x.y.com
  gateways:
    - x-gw
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: x
---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: x-ingress-policy
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: x-ingress
  action: DENY
  rules:
    - from:
        - source:
            ipBlocks: ["0.0.0.0/0"]
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: x
  labels:
    app: x
spec:
  hosts:
    - x.y.com
  gateways:
    - x-gw
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: x
```

The above should be blocking all traffic to the GW, as it matches on the CIDR range of `0.0.0.0/0`

I am entirely misunderstanding the concept of GWs/AuthorizationPolicies or have I missed something?

**Edit**
I ended up creating another GW which had the IP restriction block on that, as classic load balancers on AWS do not support IP forwarding.

```yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: istiocontrolplane
spec:
  profile: demo
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
      - name: admin-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
        label:
          istio: admin-ingressgateway
        k8s:
          serviceAnnotations:
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-all-admin
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio: admin-ingressgateway
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
    - from:
        - source:
            ipBlocks: ["176.252.114.59/32"]
```

```sh
kubectl patch svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system -p '{"spec":{"externalTrafficPolicy":"Local"}}'
```

I then used that gateway in my workload that I wanted to lock down.

Comment: I think this is  a great question to be solved, however I would suggest to create a simple diagram on current and desired scenarios, it would help to get the idea quicker and probably more answers ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know you should rather use [AuthorizationPolicy](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/) in 3 ways

- on ingress gateway
- on namespace
- on specific service

I have tried to make it work on a specific gateway with annotations like you did, but I couldn't make it work for me.

e.g.

the following authorization policy denies all requests to workloads in namespace x.

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
 name: deny-all
 namespace: x
spec:
  {}
```

the following authorization policy denies all requests on ingress gateway.

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-all
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: istio-ingressgateway
```

the following authorization policy denies all requests on [httpbin](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.7/samples/httpbin/httpbin.yaml) in x namespace.

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-service-x
  namespace: x
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: httpbin
```

---

Let's say you deny all requests on x namespace and allow only get requests for httpbin service.

Then you would use this AuthorizationPolicy to deny all requests

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-all
  namespace: x
spec:
  {}
```

And this AuthorizationPolicy to allow only get requests.

```
apiVersion: "security.istio.io/v1beta1"
kind: "AuthorizationPolicy"
metadata:
  name: "x-viewer"
  namespace: x
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: httpbin
  rules:
  - to:
    - operation:
        methods: ["GET"]
```

---

And there is the main issue ,which is ipBlocks. There is related [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/22341) about that.

As mentioned here by @incfly

> I guess the reason why it’s stop working when in non ingress pod is because the sourceIP attribute will not be the real client IP then.
>
> According to https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/22341 7, (not done yet) this aims at providing better support without setting k8s externalTrafficPolicy to local, and supports CIDR range as well.

---

I have tried this example from [istio documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-ingress/) to make it work, but it wasn't working for me, even if I changed `externalTrafficPolicy`. Then a workaround with [envoyfilter](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/) came from above istio discuss thread.

Answer provided by @hleal18 [here](https://discuss.istio.io/t/authorization-policy-ip-allow-deny-not-working-on-services-different-than-ingress-gateway/7845/4?u=pikapika).

> Got and example working successfully using EnvoyFilters, specifically with remote_ip condition applied on httbin.
>
> Sharing the manifest for reference.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: httpbin
  namespace: foo
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: httpbin
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
              subFilter:
                name: "envoy.router"
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: envoy.filters.http.rbac 
          config:
            rules:
              action: ALLOW
              policies:
                "ip-premissions":
                  permissions:
                    - any: true
                  principals:
                    - remote_ip:
                        address_prefix: xxx.xxx.xx.xx
                        prefix_len: 32
```

---

I have tried above envoy filter on my test cluster and as far as I can see it's working.

Take a look at below steps I made.

1.I have changed the externalTrafficPolicy with

```
kubectl patch svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system -p '{"spec":{"externalTrafficPolicy":"Local"}}'
```

2.I have created namespace x with istio-injection enabled and deployed httpbin here.

```
kubectl create namespace x
kubectl label namespace x istio-injection=enabled
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.7/samples/httpbin/httpbin.yaml -n x
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/samples/httpbin/httpbin-gateway.yaml -n x
```

3.I have created envoyfilter

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: httpbin
  namespace: x
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: httpbin
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
              subFilter:
                name: "envoy.router"
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: envoy.filters.http.rbac
          config:
            rules:
              action: ALLOW
              policies:
                "ip-premissions":
                  permissions:
                    - any: true
                  principals:
                    - remote_ip:
                        address_prefix: xx.xx.xx.xx
                        prefix_len: 32
```

**address_prefix** is the **CLIENT_IP**, there are commands I have used to get it.

```
export INGRESS_HOST=$(kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}')
export INGRESS_PORT=$(kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="http2")].port}')
curl "$INGRESS_HOST":"$INGRESS_PORT"/headers -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n"
CLIENT_IP=$(curl "$INGRESS_HOST":"$INGRESS_PORT"/ip -s | grep "origin" | cut -d'"' -f 4) && echo "$CLIENT_IP"
```

4.I have test it with curl and my browser.

```
curl "$INGRESS_HOST":"$INGRESS_PORT"/headers -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n"
200
```

[image]

---

Let me know if you have any more questions, I might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks Jakub. While that hasn't worked (I think the HTTPS ingress is meddling somewhere) it has really helped along my way to solving this problem. Thanks!